# C++: Correctly overriding virtual function in template class

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, virtual

Consider following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyTempl
{
    virtual void doStuff(const T &value) = 0;
};

struct MyImpl : MyTempl<int>
{
    void doStuff(const int &value) {}
};

struct MyPtrImpl : MyTempl<int*>
{
    void doStuff(const int* &value) {}
};

MyImpl imp1;
MyPtrImpl imp2;
```

This will not compile correctly: the compiler tells me that `doStuff()` in `MyPtrImpl` is pure virtual, ie. I failed to correctly override it. If I however typedef `int*` to something like `int_ptr`, and use that as the template argument for `MyPtrImpl`, everything works out.

Why is the compiler unable to deduct my intent without the typedef?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You didn't specify the correct parameter type of the virtual function and thus you're not overriding it. This results in an abstract class since the virtual function is pure.

When specifying a parameter of a const reference type like

```
void doStuff(const int & value) {}
```

it's actually an alternative to write

```
void doStuff(int const & value) {}
```

which should be considered the "normal" way to declare a constant reference. When read from right to left this means "a reference to constant `int`". Applying the same pattern to the pointer type `int*` results in

```
void doStuff(int* const & value) {}
```

[which compiles fine](http://ideone.com/mTGWjJ). But that one can't be written in the order like above, since that would mean something different: read `const int* &` from right to left and you get "a reference to a pointer to a constant `int`".

As you mentioned it, an alternative which works with the order from above can be written if you use typedef to alias the pointer type `int*`:

```
typedef int *T;
void doStuff(const T & value) {}
```

[which also compiles fine](http://ideone.com/xmL0lP), since `T` is now seen as a single literal type not introducing the ambiguities from above. In other words, the only option for how to read `const T &` is "a reference to a const `T`, which itself is a pointer to `int`". It's a bit difficult to understand it intuitively, but what's not possible is to understand this as "a reference to a pointer to a constant `int`", since this would not have *a single* `T` in the description.

I recommend to use the keyword `override` if you're using a C++11 compiler in order to detect problems like this (there are scenarios in which this problem will not result into a compilation error but into unexpected behavior; for example if the virtual function was *not* pure):

```
void doStuff(int* const & value) override {}
//                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ... which is why the *right* location of `const` is always the right. +1

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yet most people use the *left* version. Including most of the code in the standard specification if I remember correctly...

Comment: 'read `const int* &` from right to left and you get "a reference to a pointer to a constant int".' - that's all I needed to know, thanks!